# Android how to add many menus for different tabs

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs, android-tabactivity

I have many tabs like this:

```
TabHost th;
TabSpec spec;
th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost_template_two_tabs);
th.setup();
// all tab
spec = th.newTabSpec("All");
spec.setIndicator("All");
spec.setContent(R.id.tab_template_two_tabs_all);
th.addTab(spec);
// favorite tab
spec = th.newTabSpec("Favorite");
spec.setIndicator("Favorite");
spec.setContent(R.id.tab_template_two_tabs_favorite);
th.addTab(spec);
```

and for each tab i want to add a menu, how please?

Comment: Menu meaning the menu that pops up when clicking the hardware menu button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `Tab`in the `TabHost` has a number starting from 0, so you have to know which tab you are in now by using `int currentTab = th.getCurrentTab();` and then clear the previous menu by using `menu.clear()` then adding your new menu by using `inflater.inflater(menuID, menu)`

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        int currentTab = th.getCurrentTab();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), currentTab+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        if (currentTab == 0){
            menu.clear();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.first, menu);}
        else{
            menu.clear();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.second, menu);}
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

## note:

`onCreateOptionsMenu` will not help you in your case